# jquery form only passing first select box values on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm new posting here, have visited several times over the years to read every ones ideas.

My issue is I have a form with 2 select boxes, second one populated with values upon selection in the first. The second holds a url value which you got to upon submit.
This function works perfectly using the onchange but on submit only the first of the second select list urls work. I can swap them but only the first works, all the others only pass the primary url followed by a crosshatch '#'.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){

$("#category").change(function() {
    $('select[name="product"]').removeAttr("name").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show().attr("name", "product");
});

/* ' This works on all
$(".product").change(function() {
    document.location = $(this).val();
});
*/

/* this only passes url on first product option list else passes opening url + #*/
$('#discover').submit(function() {    
        document.location = $(".product").val();
    return false;
});

});

</script>

<div id="discover-box">
<form id="discover" method="post">
<fieldset>
<p class="category">

<label class="title">Category:</label>
<select id="category" name="category">
        <option value="#" selected="selected">Choose category</option>
        <option value="accommodation">Accommodation</option>
        <option value="food">Food</option>
        <option value="explore">Explore</option>
</select>

<p><label>Sub-Category:</label>

<select id="accommodation" name="product" class="product">
<option value="#" selected="selected">Choose sub-category</option>
<option value="accommodation_category.asp?o=1&c=1">Motels</option>
<option value="accommodation_category.asp?o=2&c=2">Camping, Caravan & Holiday Parks</option>
<option value="accommodation_category.asp?o=3&c=3">B&B, Self-Contained Houses & Cottages</option>
<option value="accommodation_category.asp?o=4&c=4">Hotels</option>
<option value="accommodation_category.asp?o=5&c=5">Backpackers & Group Accommodation</option>
        <option value="accommodation_category.asp?o=6&c=6">National Parks</option>
</select>

<select id="food" style="display:none" name="product" class="product">
<option value="#" selected="selected">Choose sub-category</option>
<option value="food_wine_category.asp?o=1&t=1&c=1">Restaurants & Cafes</option>
<option value="food_wine_category.asp?o=2&t=1&c=2">Pubs</option>
<option value="food_wine_category.asp?o=3&t=1&c=3">Bakeries & Takeaway</option>
<option value="food_wine_category.asp?o=4&t=1&c=4">Local Produce</option>
<option value="food_wine_category.asp?o=5&t=2&c=1">Mount Gambier Wine Region</option>
<option value="food_wine_category.asp?o=5&t=2&c=2">Other Limestone Coast Wine Regions</option>
</select>

<select id="explore" style="display:none" name="product" class="product">
<option value="#" selected="selected">Choose sub-category</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=1">Top 10</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=2">Arts, Crafts, Galleries & Museums</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=3">Heritage, Antiques & Collectables</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=4">Family Fun</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=5">Caves & Sinkholes</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=6">Parks & Gardens</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=7">Walks & Drives</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=8">Kanawinka Geotrail</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=9">Retail</option>
<option value="explore_category.asp?o=10">Recreation, Leisure & Adventure</option>  
</select>

</p>
<p class="buttons">
        <input type="image" src="images/submit-red.png" Value="submit">
</p>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it because all the 3 select box are using the same name 'product'?

Comment: You're selecting more than one element with $(".product"). Have you tried using `$(".product").each(function() { /* ... */ });`?

Comment: don't get where you mean, im assuming its in the submit section as if I remove the submit function and use the change it all works.
Do you mean to alter here?: $(".product").val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because $(".product").val(); will find first occurrence of DOM having class product so in any case it will fetch first one... u can do this using

```
$('#discover').submit(function() {    
       document.location = $('select[name="product"]').val();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: spot on, that's it, all good. Funny this is I tried that (or similar) unsuccessfully. Must have got the syntax wrong. Much appreciated, I have been battling this for 2 days. Could have worked around but wanted to learn from it. Thanks Mitali & everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Open Fiddler (fiddler2.com) and watch the post go past.  I find that generally when more than one control on a page uses the same name, the browser actually passes all of them, but the server-side framework expecting each post parameter to be unique, ignores all but the last one.

Answer (score 0):

when you submit , you have only one select box with attribute **name** ,so you can select the selected value by that attribute

```
$('#discover').submit(function() {    
        document.location = $('select[name="product"]').val();
    return false;
});
```